# How to set IIS to return 404 for strange characters in urls like these ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃ?

Tags: asp.net, iis

When I checked my server log file, I saw bingbot keep requesting urls with strange characters. But it sometimes return status 200/500.  How to set IIS to return 404 for strange characters in urls like these ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what types of things you're trying to filter (that's not clear here), there may be some configuration-only way to do this, but the simplest way I've found for stuff like this is just to route all requests through to `global.asax`, using the following `web.config`entry:

```
...
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
...
```

and then adding the following code to your `global.asax's` `Application_BeginRequest` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// The global web application object.
/// </summary>
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Request.Url.Contains("ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃ"))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you'd need to change the 'if' statement to do whatever logic you need to filter out the offending requests (and be sure NOT to filter out any requests that you really want).  You could also check the `User-Agent` header to see if it's the BingBot (from your question not completely sure if that matters either).

Comment: This solution solves the strange characters problem in the server log files.  But I had another problem with URLs indexed by Bing.  When I checked my bing webmaster tools, I found some other URLs indexed with different types of strange characters like these "¥ââ¤ã¥â".  These will return Bad Request - Invalid URL 400 even with the solution above.  Do you have any suggestions on how to solve it? thanks.

Comment: Are you on ASP.NET 4.x?  There is a new setting in that version that causes IIS to filter out some requests before they get to ASP, ostensibly because the characters could be used for security exploits.  IIRC, the setting is called requestValidationMode and if you set it to "2.0", it is less strict and most requests will get though to your global.asax where you can filter them.  If you google requestValidationMode, you should be able to find the exact location of that setting and a description of what it does.  This might be what is causing the Bad Request returns.

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't work. It still returning the same Bad Request. I have found a character that's causing the bad request. I couldn't paste that particular character here because it just it just goes missing.  But I don't have enough points to post an image of the character here in my post.

Comment: Hopefully this will give you some direction: http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/troubleshooting-http-400-errors-in-iis.  At least it should help you understand whether it's ASP or IIS that is doing the blocking.  Keep in mind that there is a reason IIS and ASP do this blocking, so you should understand the reasons the blocking was put in place before disabling it.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I think is iis that is doing the blocking. I used fiddler to see the raw URL that's been sent to the server and found that the invalid characters were encoded before it gets sent to the server. One of the character set that I'm pretty sure is causing the problem was "%C2%8D" or just "%8D". How can I set iis to return 404 instead of 400 so to make Bing to deindex those invalid URLs?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible.  If it is, it's outside my expertise and probably warrants a search and possibly a new question.  Good luck!